# AspectJ advice not executing

Tags: java, aspectj

I have searched Baeldung and MKyong among other sites. Everything looks good, but my advise is not executing. I read somewhere about having multiple pointcuts in one aspect, so I have created separate aspects for each pointcut, still no avail. I am trying to do load-time weaving.

One of my aspect classes

```
@Aspect
public class AuditUpdateAspect {
    @Before("execution(* com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionUpdate.update*(..))")
    public void beforeUpdate(JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.println("Update");
        Object o = jp.getArgs()[0];
        if (o instanceof Auditable) {
            Auditable auditable = (Auditable)o;
            auditable.setOsUserName(AuditHelper.getAuditName());
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Client code

```
// SessionHelper is a helper class with static methods to get stateless EJBs from JNDI
// getUpdate() returns an instance of KdsSessionUpdateBean which implements the KdsSessionUpdate interface
// updateIssue(Issue issue) is a method in KdsSessionUpdateBean
SessionHelper.getUpdate().updateIssue(issue);
```

The weaving happens as you can see in the following: here is program startup

```
[AppClassLoader@4d885088] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.2 built on Thursday Aug 14, 2014 at 21:45:02 GMT
[AppClassLoader@4d885088] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4d885088
[AppClassLoader@4d885088] info using configuration /C:/Users/bray/eclipse-workspaces/combined-workspace/audit/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@4d885088] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditCreateAspect
[AppClassLoader@4d885088] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditRemoveAspect
[AppClassLoader@4d885088] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditUpdateAspect
[MethodUtil@6b429a7d] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.2 built on Thursday Aug 14, 2014 at 21:45:02 GMT
[MethodUtil@6b429a7d] info register classloader sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil@6b429a7d
[MethodUtil@6b429a7d] info using configuration /C:/Users/bray/eclipse-workspaces/combined-workspace/audit/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[MethodUtil@6b429a7d] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditCreateAspect
[MethodUtil@6b429a7d] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditRemoveAspect
[MethodUtil@6b429a7d] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditUpdateAspect
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[AppClassLoader@4d885088] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
```

Here is a call to `SessionHelper.getUpdate().updateIssue(issue);`. This is abbreviated, as it was too long for the post.

```
[AppClassLoader@305f387c] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionUpdateBean.updatePublisherRemitTransRemitIdById(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer))' in Type 'com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionUpdateBean' (KdsSessionUpdateBean.java:64) advised by before advice from 'com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditUpdateAspect' (AuditUpdateAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@305f387c] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionUpdateBean.updateIssue(com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.entity.Issue))' in Type 'com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionUpdateBean' (KdsSessionUpdateBean.java:641) advised by before advice from 'com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditUpdateAspect' (AuditUpdateAspect.java)
```

So it appears as if the weaving at load time is happening, but the two `System.out.println("Update");` and `System.out.println("Done");` don't get executed.

Edit: including aop.xml as requested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditCreateAspect"/>
        <aspect name="com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditRemoveAspect"/>
        <aspect name="com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditUpdateAspect"/>
        <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
            <include within="com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.*"/>
        </weaver>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Edit: Test code for MCVE

```
public AuditTestApp() {
    WholesalerGroup wholesalerGroup = new WholesalerGroup();
    wholesalerGroup.setCorporationGroupId(new Integer(1000));
    wholesalerGroup.setDescription("Test Wholesaler Group For Auditing");
    wholesalerGroup.setOldCode("OLD_CODE");
    System.out.println(String.format("Audit before create (%s)", wholesalerGroup.getOsUserName()));
    WholesalerGroup addedWholesalerGroup = SessionHelper.getCreate().createWholesalerGroup(wholesalerGroup);
    System.out.println(String.format("Audit after create (%s)", addedWholesalerGroup.getOsUserName()));
    addedWholesalerGroup.setCorporationGroupId(new Integer(2000));
    SessionHelper.getUpdate().updateWholesalerGroup(addedWholesalerGroup);
    System.out.println(String.format("Audit after update (%s)", addedWholesalerGroup.getOsUserName()));
    SessionHelper.getRemove().removeWholesalerGroup(addedWholesalerGroup);
    System.out.println("Finishing");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Edit: Output after replacing EJBs with simple code

```
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.2 built on Thursday Aug 14, 2014 at 21:45:02 GMT
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3b756db3
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] info using configuration /C:/Users/bray/eclipse-workspaces/combined-workspace/audit/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditCreateAspect
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditRemoveAspect
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] info register aspect com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditUpdateAspect
Audit before create (null)
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.entity.WholesalerGroup com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionCreateBean.createWholesalerGroup(com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.entity.WholesalerGroup))' in Type 'com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionCreateBean' (KdsSessionCreateBean.java:8) advised by before advice from 'com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditCreateAspect' (AuditCreateAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionRemoveBean.removeWholesalerGroup(com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.entity.WholesalerGroup))' in Type 'com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionRemoveBean' (KdsSessionRemoveBean.java:8) advised by before advice from 'com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditRemoveAspect' (AuditRemoveAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@3b756db3] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionUpdateBean.updateWholesalerGroup(com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.entity.WholesalerGroup))' in Type 'com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.session.KdsSessionUpdateBean' (KdsSessionUpdateBean.java:8) advised by before advice from 'com.kable.newsstand.knet.audit.AuditUpdateAspect' (AuditUpdateAspect.java)
Create
Done
Audit after create (:BRay:knc3940:192.168.1.7)
Update
Done
Audit after update (:BRay:knc3940:192.168.1.7)
Remove
Done
Finishing
```

Comment: It looks like the weaving is done as you expect it. Questions: (1) Do other aspects work? (2) Does using a logger instead of printing to `System.out` help? (Sometimes it is the small things...) (3) Can you please show more code, ideally something I can compile and run, i.e. an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? GitHub would be fine. At least I would like to see all aspects, classes and interfaces in question incl. package names.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also like to see your _aop.xml_.

Comment: @kriegaex I've included the aop.xml in an edit above. In trying to set up a MCVE for you, I ripped out the EJBs and replaced them with some simple classes and interfaces that mimicked the EJBs. The result looks good. I've placed the output in an edit above. I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @kriegaex To your first question, no the other aspects don't work either.

Comment: @kriegaex The whole purpose of this project is to audit changes to EJBs. The MCVE that works is here https://github.com/bcr666/audit-test-mcve and a required project https://github.com/bcr666/audit

Comment: Well, thanks for the additional information, but the whole point of an MCVE is to reproduce the problem. You are saying that it is working, i.e. it does not reproduce the problem. So you need to ask yourself what is different between MCVE and your real code. Maybe that it runs inside a container and you have some kind of classloading problem? Pure speculation. I can only help you if you can reproduce the problem for me and I can see it on my workstation.

Comment: @kriegaex I have done some refactoring. Now the only differences in the project are  importing an EJB jar in maven vs. importing a mockup EJB jar through the build path. That difference is what makes or breaks it though. So I am still lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193967/discussion-between-kriegaex-and-bcr666).

Comment: Sorry I could not help you but I am interested if you could solve your problem and how. If still unsolved, help me reproduce it by updating your GitHub MCVE.

Comment: @kriegaex I never did solve it. I believe it has something to do with making EJB calls to a remote server. It was decided by my team that instead of further research, we would include a logging field on every table and just use an interceptor on the server side to catch that field and log it to the auditing table.

Comment: Hm, I think I could have helped you with this, but I would have needed more information. But if you found an alternative solution - although it sounds pretty ugly to me because you achieve the opposite of extracting the cross-cutting concern logging from your application via AOP by building logging knowledge into the application and even the database. Thanks for the feedback.